# What does this error mean in my IIS7 Failed Request Tracing report?

Tags: iis-7, permissions, http-authentication

when I attempt to goto any page in my web application (i'm migrating the code from an asp.net web *site* to web *application*, and now testing it) .. i keep getting some not authenticated error(s) .

So, i've turned on FREB and this is what it says...

[image]

I'm not sure what that means?

Secondly, i've also made sure that my site (or at least the default document which has been setup to be default.aspx) has *anonymous on* and the rest off. Proof: -

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list config "My Web App/default.aspx" -section:anonymousAuthentication
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd list config "My Web App" -section:anonymousAuthentication
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <authentication>
      <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" />
    </authentication>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

401.3 means that you're past the authentication phase, but access has been denied due to the ACL on the resource itself - in this case, possibly c:\users\blank\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\blank\webapplication1. This would not be unexpected, as typically IUSR would not have access to files underneath a user profile.  Try moving (copying) the app underneath c:\inetpub instead.

Comment: kewl :) it was an ACL issue. cheers!